# Server side rendering of reactjs for express?

Tags: reactjs, express, viewengine

What is the best view engine/ method to pre-render a react component on an express backend? I'm at a loss at finding the most appropriate way to do it, all I can find in regards to resources are a bunch of article-tutorials, but they all do it in a different way, so I'm wondering if there is a recommended convention.

Essentially I just want to show 1 component with a bunch of pre-set props. No navigation or anything, just for 1 endpoint. I.e. You go to /component and it returns `<Component prop1={1}/>`

Comment: Take a look at [`next.js`](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `renderToString` or `renderToStaticMarkup` methods if you just want the single component rendered and then send it in your response.

See: [ReactDOMServer](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html)